# To show built in Calendar control on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, popup, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two version of my application.

1. Using built in asp.net calendar control
2. Using jQuery DatePicker

Both has it's cons... and pros.

Asp.net calendar control is great so far due its events in c# side, but I am not able to pop it up when a button is clicked.
where as, jQuery datepicker is extremely portable and can be pop up from anywhere but it's not having events and other functionalities that are easily available in calendar control.

Given this scenario, how can I use the asp.net calendar control to be popped up when button is clicked?

### **EDIT**

[I have found a site and going to try it out: create-popup-date-picker-using-aspnet-calendar-control](http://blog.divergencehosting.com/2009/03/11/create-popup-date-picker-using-aspnet-calendar-control/)

There's an issue with the above post. The calendar definitely pops up - **BUT** it pushes down all the other controls unlike jQuery DatePicker's smooth rendering... is there a way to fix this part?

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">  
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>  

<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  

<asp:CalendarExtender   
    ID="CalendarExtender1"   
    TargetControlID="txtStartDate"   
    runat="server" />
```

`Ajax` CalendarExtender works. Click or tab into the TextBox will popup calendar

Comment: But OP says it about the button not the texbox. Upvote for simplest code and just these 3 lines do the work

Comment: @MohitShrivastava will `CalendarExtender` have same events as of `Calendar`? Further yes I don't need a textbox being attached, and must be a button.

Comment: I havent checked that ... i just checked the popping up. please do study b4 u implement :) Cheers!!!

Comment: @MohitShrivastava this can't be used in our implementation. Answerer seems to expect that `every typical` asp web application has AJAX toolkit by default. It isn't...

Comment: @bonCodigo - I agree with you. but i like this piece of code thats it. Sure bugfree needs to look specific towards your question

Comment: @BugFreeSolution  I am generous on upvoting always. But solution must at least satisfy the basics. In my question I haven't mentioned about AJAX Took Kit controls. So if you are giving a solution with a different set of controls, then you must specify a line like `Make sure you have AjaxControlToolkit.dll in your bin folder`. In order to implement your answer there has to be more researched to be done. This doesn't solve my *problem*. An answer shouldn't just help one person nor the question.

Comment: Thanks @bonCodigo I'll do more research and try to solve the question without AjaxControlToolkit ...

Comment: That would be great. [And please quote the site **if** you have take code snippets from it.](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_calendar_simple.ashx)